# get a PolyLine path to go to center of screen

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to draw a polyLine to the center of the screen (as the second path, point B) ... I tried referencing the below to get center: any pointers?

```
  coordinatesBx = map.extent.getCenter().getLatitude();
  coordinatesBy = map.extent.getCenter().getLongitude();
```

The above errors with **cannot `getCenter()` of undefined...** should I try to get this in `screenPoints` first, then try to convert to lat long?

I am good with my first two start points as lat long coords, *i.e.* `workingStartA` and `workingStartB`; however I cannot get the second `coordinatesBx` and `coordinatesBy` to go to **center of screen**. I am in arcgis-JS 4.11 specifically.

*i.e.*

```
  var polyline = {
      type: "polyline",
      paths: [
          [workingStartA, workingStartB],
          [coordinatesBx, coordinatesBy]
      ]
  };
```

---

**Update:**

Here is my map; I essentially just want to call the center property lat and long; It works when I manually enter it as the below; but I would like to call it as a variable and have it update automatically when mapview is updated.

```
const view = new view ({
    center: [-93.70, 38.65], // can i grab this as two vars?
    container: 'mapview',
    map: esriMap,
    zoom: 5
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using API 3 (I think this is the one you are using it), then what it might be happening is that you are not waiting for the map to load.

`map.on("load", function () {console.log(map.extent);});`

On the new API (API 4), you need to get the data from the view. Here, the view has a [center](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html#center) property, something like this:

```
let coordinateBx = view.center.x;
let coordinateBy = view.center.y;
```

A full example using one from API docs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"
    />
    <title>Intro to MapView - Create a 2D map - 4.14</title>
    <style>
      html,
      body,
      #viewDiv {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.14/esri/themes/light/main.css"
    />
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.14/"></script>

    <script>
      require(["esri/Map", "esri/views/MapView", "esri/Graphic"], function(
        Map,
        MapView,
        Graphic
      ) {
        var map = new Map({
          basemap: "streets"
        });

        var view = new MapView({
          container: "viewDiv",
          map: map,
          zoom: 4,
          center: [15, 65] // longitude, latitude
        });

        console.log(`x:${view.center.x} y:${view.center.y}`);
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="viewDiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look; I am on version 4.11 unfortunately -- I've updated my question with more details.

Comment: Can you post the code when you create the map and the view?

Comment: I have it in const like       const view = app.mapview; 
      const map = view.map;

Comment: I've added the initial map instance; can I call the center property as two vars?

Comment: Like I mention you need to use the center property of the view, I have updated the answer with an example.